# Java - looping in try-catch block

Tags: java

I am working on writing a file reader, and the idea is to have the user enter a number that represents the line number from the text file.  The variable that holds this number is of type `int`. However, when the user enters a `String` instead, Java throws the `InputMismatchException` exception, and what I want is to have a loop in the `catch` clause, where I will be looping until the user enters a valid value, i.e. an `int`.  The skeleton looks like this:

```
 public void _____ throws IOException {
    try {
    // Prompting user for line number
    // Getting number from keyboard
    // Do something with number
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
       // I want to loop until the user enters a valid input
       // When the above step is achieved, I am invoking another method here
    }  
}
```

My question is, what are some possible techniques that could do the validation? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using exceptions for flow control. Catch the exception, but only print a message. Also, do need for loops within loops.

It's as simple as this:

```
public void _____ throws IOException {
    int number = -1;
    while (number == -1) {
        try {
            // Prompt user for line number
            // Getting number from keyboard, which could throw an exception
            number = <get from input>;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
             System.out.println("That is not a number!");
        }  
    }
    // Do something with number
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works, but I had to add an extra String ___ = __.nextLine() after the prompt in the `catch` clause.

Answer (score 4):

```
while(true){ 
   try { 
        // Prompting user for line number 
        // Getting number from keyboard 
        // Do something with number 
        //break; 
       } catch (InputMismatchException e) { 
            // I want to loop until the user enters a valid input 
            // When the above step is achieved, I am invoking another method here 
       } 
   }
```

Comment: You even don't need use this boolean variable. just use `while(true)` and break the cycle when data is properly read.

Comment: agree with Yarg 7

while(true){
 try {
    // Prompting user for line number
    // Getting number from keyboard
    // Do something with number
      break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
       // I want to loop until the user enters a valid input
       // When the above step is achieved, I am invoking another method here
    }  
}

Comment: When I tried either solution, I have an infinite loop.  What I was looking for is a way to validate the number itself. I was thinking of obtaining the number's ASCII value, and if it is out of an appropriate range, then keep looping.

Comment: did you mean this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the `Exception`

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(sc.hasNextLine())
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    if (isNumeric(input) {
        // do something
        // with the number
        break; // break the loop
    }
}
```

The method `isNumeric`:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    return str.matches("^[0-9]+$");
}
```

If you want use a dialog for input number:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a number:"); // show input dialog
```